# Copy-item runas Administrator to program file fail

Tags: powershell, permissions, administrator, copy-item, start-process

i would like to copy the license folder and overwrite the existing folder, since it is program file (x86), i have to run the elevated powershell, i am able to copy it when i launch it manually, just wonder is it possible to get all run at one line (all at once) ?  really appreicated

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("R:", "\\roa\smdd\Software\Mest", $false)

Start-process Powershell.exe -ArgumentList " Copy-Item "R:\Licenses\" "C:\Program Files `(x86`)\Mest Research S.L\Mest\licenses"" -force -recurse -wait
```

Comment: Why the escape Char in front of $net? Why even store the new-object in a variable if you are not using that variable later

Comment: @ArcSet looks like it's just a formatting oops. They have backticks before and after their entire codeblock, so it looks like they just didn't know how to format it. (I edited the question to correct it)

Comment: To ArcSet,      the escape char is added when i click on the "add code" function while i try to copy the my file correctly format way.

Comment: Also lastly Did you mean....How can i make this all one line?

Comment: sorry for the bad editing, Yes ArcSet, i mean all at one line .  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map a drive or invoke `powershell.exe`. The code is PowerShell, so you don't need to spin up a new copy of PowerShell to run the `Copy-Item` cmdlet to copy files. You only need one PowerShell command:

```
Copy-Item "\\roa\smdd\Software\Mest\Licenses\*" "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Mest Research S.L\Mest\licenses" -Force -Recurse
```

Note that you will likely need to open PowerShell as administrator (elevated) to be able to copy items into that directory.

Comment: it giving me error saying " could not find a part of the path 'C:\Mestrelab Research S.L\Mest\Licenses'. after i copy it over. do you have solution?

Comment: Make sure the environment variable named `ProgramFiles(x86)` exists and is set correctly. (That variable will not exist on a 32-bit system; you would need to use the `ProgramFiles` environment variable instead.)